# Retrofit with RxJava - custom failure data class

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I have an API which sends me errors with a custom JSON under 500 error

so, here's my Api Interface:

```
  @POST("${API_PREFIX}method")
  fun callForIt(@Body request: MyRequest) : Single<MyResponse>
```

And here's how I call it:

```
api.callForIt(request)
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(
     {
      // Here I get perfect MyResponse object
     },
     {
      // And here I get only throwable, but need to get info from the json
     })
```

So, what I want is to describe a custom data class like

```
data class ErrorResponse(
  val type: String,
  val fatal: Boolean,
  val msg: String
// etc
)
```

because the server is sending me valuable info in JSON and I need to obtain it, so is there any way to read it from `onFailure()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ t: Throwable ->
    if (t is HttpException) {
        val errorMsg = t.response()!!.errorBody()!!.string()
        val errorResponse = Gson().fromJson(errorMsg, ErrorResponse::class)
        // handle the error with errorResponse...
    }
    else {
        // handle the error with code >=500...
    }
}
```